# Changing the font style and border size in mapbox default map

Tags: mapbox

How do we change the font style and border size in mapbox default map?
Is custom tile using tilemill the only option. or do i need to upgrade the account on mapbox to have this feature?

Thanks,
DB

Comment: By using google and reading articles,books.Docs related to your question. And then when u are stuck with A CODING issue you post it here

Comment: The font is not able to be changed yet as of TileMill v1, though this will come in http://github.com/mapbox/tm2. For the border, check out [styling lines](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/styling-lines/) in the TileMill docs. You won't be able to do this on the default Mapbox OpenStreetMap-based map, but you could make your own with source data from OSM or elsewhere and style it like this.